# How to change tmp folder location, used by server for WAR's needs and file upload?

Tags: linux, upload, wildfly

I use a WildFly 10 on Linux. There are several WARs and EARs deployed on this server. One of them lets an end user uploads patches to the server. A <t:inputFileUpload> (tomahawk.jar by Apache) is used for this action. At the first step, a patch file is uploaded to the /tmp/. Then it's copied or deployed to the $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/appName.war/. But there is not a lot of free space in /opt/ folder and if the user uploads a big patch a "No space left on device" java.io.IOException appears. How can I specify that the server should use another folder instead of $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/appName.war/? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to research "deployment overlays". There is an API for that that might point you at the right direction for handling deployment failures.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is founded. Either @MultipartConfig(location="/tmp") can be used in servlet class or <multipart-config> tag can be used in servlet definition in WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<multipart-config>
    <location>/tmp</location>    
</multipart-config>
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets011.htm